# Python regex multiple matches occurrences between two strings

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a multi-line string with my start/end magic strings ("X" and "Y"). I'm trying to capture all occurrences but I'm experiencing some issues.

Here is the code

```py
testString = '''AAAAAXBBBBBYCCCCCXDDDDDYEEEEEEXFFF
FFFYGGG
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)X(.*)Y(.*)', re.MULTILINE)

match = re.search(pattern, testString)
print match.group(1) # output: AAAAAXBBBBBYCCCCC
print match.group(2) # output: DDDDD
print match.group(3) # output: EEEEEEXFFF
```

Basically, I'm trying to capture all occurrences of the following (And I have to maintain text order):

- Text before the magic start string (e.g.: AAAAA, CCCCC, EEEEEE)
- Text between start/end magic strings (e.g.: BBBBB, DDDDD, FFF\nFFF)
- Text after the magic start string (e.g.: CCCCC, GGG)

So I'm trying to print the following output: (what's in between brackets below is just a comment)

```
AAAAA (before magic string)
BBBBB (between magic strings)
CCCCC (before/after magic strings, it does not matter. Just the order matters.)
DDDDD (after magic string)
```

And so on. Printing them in that order would solve the issue. (Then I can pass each to other functions, ...etc.)

The code works nicely when the text is as simple as for example "AAXBBYCC", but with complicated strings I'm losing control.

Any ideas or alternative ways to do this?

Comment: What exactly are those "complicated strings" and what is your exact expected output? For example, there may be ambiguities and/or interleaving occurrences like in `X1X2Y3X4Y`

Comment: I edited the original post with examples from the testString in the code. I want to get all occurrences of text before or after, it does not matter. And I want to get text in between each of them. It's basically used in a parser for further text processing. (so I have to maintain the order of the processed text).

Comment: Where you wrote _after the magic start_, did you mean _after the magic end_? And why didn't you include _EEEEEE_ there?

Comment: @j0kzy What made you accept that particular answer when it does not seem to give the output you stated you wanted in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match any character except X or Y in group 1 and then match X and do the same for Y. The "after the magic string" part you could capture in a lookahead with a third group.

The [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) using  `[^` will also match an newline to match the `FFFFFF` part.

```
([^XY]+)X([^XY]+)Y(?=([^XY]+))
```

- `([^XY]+)X` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except X or Y, then match X
- `([^XY]+)Y` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except X or Y, then match Y
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `([^XY]+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ times any char except X or Y
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jRwnE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AhsHph)

```
import re

regex = r"([^XY]+)X([^XY]+)Y(?=([^XY]*))"

s = ("AAAAAXBBBBBYCCCCCXDDDDDYEEEEEEXFFF\n"
            "FFFYGGG")

matches = re.findall(regex, s)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
[('AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC'), ('CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'EEEEEE'), ('EEEEEE', 'FFF\nFFF', 'GGG')]
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm trying to print the following output: (what's in between brackets below is just a comment)
>
> ```
> AAAAA (before magic string)
> BBBBB (between magic strings)
> CCCCC (before/after magic strings, it does not matter. Just the order matters.)
> DDDDD (after magic string)
> ```
>
> And so on.

Since it doesn't matter whether before or after start or end, it is as simple as:

```
import re
o = re.split("X|Y", testString)
print(*o, sep='\n')
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with asterisk in the print and also the "sep". Using Python 3.8.7.

Comment: Since you don't insist on the output to be exactly as shown in your question, you can as well just `print(o)`.

Comment: Yeah this would work as well with the example I provided. But the problem is that I want to know when it matched the text in between. I'm missing how to do this part still.

Comment: So there's a problem which you didn't mention in your question and you want to solve on your own?

Comment: Yeah I figured out my question was not 100% clear. Anyway, I figured out what was my problem. I had to add a `?` after the asterisk to prevent the regex from becoming greedy. And to use `finditer` to return matches in order.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'[^XY]+')
match = re.findall(pattern, testString)
print(match)
# ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'EEEEEE', 'FFF\nFFF', 'GGG\n']
```

Comment: This would also work with the example I provided. The problem is that I want to know when it matched the text in between. I'm missing how to do this part still.